# requested database driver not found on delphi 7

Tags: delphi, firebird, zeos

I have installed ZEOS on my Delphi 7 and tried connecting to a Firebird database. After I put the db path to the object inspector and tried to connect to it, Delphi always displays a message requested database driver not found. I have installed the Firebird ODBC and have set the setting on the data sources shortcut found on administrative tools but still can't connect.

How do I install the driver and where do I need to put it?

I used this connection when i tried connecting to my Firebird database

```
procedure TForm1.ZConnection1AfterConnect(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;
```

Comment: "I used this connection" seems to be missing something. You didn't provide anything having to do with the connection. You've posted an empty procedure for an event that gets called **after** the connection is made (which is why it has **AfterConnect** in it's name). If you're getting a runtime exception, post the **exact** error message you're seeing, including any error codes and other information.

Comment: Zeos doesn't use ODBC, as far as I know (I don't use it myself) it needs the `fbclient.dll` from Firebird.

Comment: With ZEOS lib you have to install some dll for the database you use. The dll are in the \zeos\lib\ directory and according to the install doc :  "Copy the required dlls for your database client to the windows system directory (usually Win-
dows\System or winnt\system32) or use the database client installer."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might be misunderstanding what Zeos is and does. It is **not** a layer that lies between your application and ODBC, ADO or whatever database access layer. Instead, it is a database access layer itself that allows you to connect natively to several databases like Firebird, SQLite and others. It does not need ODBC to be installed.

You can find an introduction to Zeos architecture at their webpage in this [article](http://zeos.firmos.at/kb.php?mode=article&k=8).

In order to connect with Firebird you will need to use a TZConnection and set following properties:

- *Database*: For example `c:/myapp/mydatabase.fdb`
- *Hostname*: localhost if the same computer.
- *Protocol*: Should be one of the Firebird protocols. `Firebird-x.x` stands for protocol to access "normal" Firebird, while `Firebirdd-x.x` is for the embedded version.
- *User*
- *Password*

You can set additional properties but for a basic connection that should do it.

Regarding the error you mention, I suspect you are trying to use the embedded version. In that case, make sure the DLL mentiones by @Mark is in the same path as the app executable. If it is a regular Firebird installation make sure its path is included in the system path.

HTH